# Выравнивание div'ов в одной строке

Tags: html, css

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
.one {width:800px; border:1px solid blue;}
.two {width:50px; border:1px solid red; height:50px;}

<div class="one">
<div class="two" align="left"></div>
<div class="two" align="right"></div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь внутри 1 дива (one) сделать 2 дива которые выровнены по левому и правому краю. Может кто подсказать где ошибка? [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/BBTnU/5/)

p.s. исправил 1, свою ошибку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У тега `div` нет аттрибута `align`. Для выравнивания дивов по левому и правому краю используются `folat`-ы: http://jsfiddle.net/BbApE/

Comment: @fori1ton, мой вариант все-равно лаконичнее :) ... По доброму +1

Comment: на будущее нельзя, а вернее не корректно писать style в самом теге, нужно все с помощью стилей делать в css в теги ничего не пихать

Answer (score 2):

не очень ясна задача, но... если вам надо выровнять их справа и слева соответственно один под другим, то вот код:

```
<html>
  <div class="one">
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
  </div>

    <style>
        .one{
            width:800px;
            border:1px solid blue;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .one div{
            width:50px; 
            border:1px solid red;
            height:50px;
        }
        .one div:nth-child(1){
            float: left;
        }
        .one div:nth-child(2){
            clear: both;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

А если они должны быть в одной строке, то удалите строчку в стиле "clear: both;" и их выровняет в одной строке.

Примечание: делал через :nth-child, но не всеми версиями браузеров поддерживается. Это можно исправить добавив id или class для внутренних div'ов.

Второй вариант без float'ов:

```
<style>
    .one{
        width:800px;
        height: 104px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        position: relative;
    }
    .one div{
        width:50px; 
        border:1px solid red;
        height:50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .one div:nth-child(1){
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    .one div:nth-child(2){
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Каким пользоваться зависит от задач.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/khYJv/1/ без использования лишнего div'a.

Что касается атрибута align, то он устарел и использовать его не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

align это выравнивание непосредственно внутри этого блока а не самого блока
нужно через float, ниже пример
http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/7E9Yg/